# Return string in a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to get somes fields of a DB to import in another DB. So, I've connected to my DB with mysqli.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "db_name");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "$mysqli->connect_errno";
} else {
    echo "You're IN"."<br />";
}
```

Now, I select the PK of the table:

```
$emails = $mysqli->query("SELECT email FROM customers WHERE date_first_order IS NOT NULL AND date_first_download IS NOT NULL");
```

I know that I've an array at this moment in $emails. So, I use a foreach loop.

```
foreach($emails as $email) {
        $email = $email["cl_email"];
        $query_name = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM customers WHERE email = $email");

        $query_lastname = $mysqli->query("SELECT lastname FROM customers WHERE email = $email");
        echo $email." ".$query_name." ".$query_lastname."<br />";

    }
```

Here is my problem, with the query_name and query_lastname vars I get an array, an not an String. So, How I can get the field that I'm looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to `var_dump()` the result?

Comment: Parse the result set and get the data you need .

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1

Comment: Also in your query shows `SELECT email..`. But in iteration you could get `$email["cl_email"];`. How its possible to get?

Comment: "I know that I've an array at this moment in $emails" - no, you have not array, but [pointer to resultset](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using MySQLi you should use `mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()` if you want to get each row as an associative array. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is a string, and you should firstly place it into `''`.

```
$relation= $mysqli->query("SELECT name, lastname FROM customers WHERE email = $email");
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------^------^
```

And fetch row.

```
$row = $relation->fetch_row());
```

Secondly, you can simply return from array the wanted key.

```
echo $email . " " . $row["name"] . " " . $row["lastname"] . "<br />";
```

Comment: Good answer, but I've use finally fetch-assoc() and it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @jonathon mysqli-result::fetch-assoc() should help you with this. Also, i don't see any reason you have to do these queries. I believe you can get the desired output into single query too :)

`$query_name = $mysqli->query("SELECT email,name,lastname FROM customers WHERE date_first_order IS NOT NULL AND date_first_download IS NOT NULL");
while ($row = $query_name->fetch_assoc()) {
    print $row['email'].$row['name'].$row['lastname'];
}`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm doing this query for import this data in a new DB.

Answer (score 0):

You could use implode(",",$yourvariable);
It changes your array to a string. you may want to separate the results with a comma or you can just put  ("",$yourvariable);
Hope this helps!:)